# Black lines at the border of graphics

Tags: plotting, version-10

For a while I seem to have a problem with default black borders on plots.
For instance,

```
Plot3D[Re[Sin[x + I y]], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {y, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, 
 ClippingStyle -> None]
```

generates a picture

[image]

with black lines on the bottom and rhs of the picture.

Is there a simple way for dealing with this issue? I'm using versions 10.1-10.3 for Windows (W7 64). Seems that this problem does not appear on Linux.

Comment: I do not get these lines with your code in Mma 10.3, Win7/64, and have never seen such with the previous Mma versions.

Comment: Yeah, it's weird. I'm getting these lines on two different machines (both with w7 64).

Comment: @GregoryRut Is it an exported graphics or a screenshot?

Comment: An exported. But I get these lines on the screen as well.

Comment: You might want to contact WRI support. Could be a hardware / gfx driver thing...

Comment: The black lines don't appear in v. 10.3 on a Mac.

Comment: @YvesKlett, will do that. It happens on two of my machines. I thought it might be a more common problem.

Comment: I had these lines with starting with 10.3 but they went away with 10.3.1.  Win 8.1 Pro 64 bit

Comment: I am fairly certain we have had a question about exactly this rendering glitch before, but at the moment I cannot find it.  Perhaps instead of closing this we should try to find the common factor.  The other one may be deleted making it harder to search for.

Comment: Confirmed on Windows 10 and mac with mathematica 13.2

Comment: `g=Graphics[{White,EdgeForm[],Rectangle[{0,0},{11,112/2}]},Background->Black,PlotRangePadding->{{0,0},{0,0}}]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard see my example, `Rasterize[g]`  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/279484/6648